# Running a script after user logs in

Tags: macos, shell, authentication, launchd

How could a script wait for the login process to complete before running a command in shell script in Mac OS X?

I have tried wait and sleep commands, but that doesn't seem to stop the script running under the root that owns the login process.

I want the script run after the user logs in.

Comment: What do you exactly do? Perhaps show the script you use?

Comment: Can you use `launchd`?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 easy(ier) options:

1. Create a **[Login Item](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/bpsystemstartup/Chapters/CreatingLoginItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW5-BAJJBJEG)**. To see an example, **[click here](http://www.macinstruct.com/node/427)**.
2. Use **[launchd](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/bpsystemstartup/chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html)**. You don't have to install anything. All you need to do is to create a configuration file to tell `launchd` what to do, and save it (with proper permissions) on a specific directory that's read by `launchd`.

Comment: Many thanks guys for your reply. I have tried launchd but that's not working for us. We have to run the script on around 1500 Macs. The current script I'm trying now is:
#!/bin/bash
ROOT_UID=0
while [[ "$UID" -eq "$ROOT_UID" ]]; do
wait
done
if [[ "$UID" -ne "$ROOT_UID" ]]; then
defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.office.plist "14\FirstRun\SetupComplete" -integer 1
defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.office.plist "14\UserInfo\UserName" -string Administrator
defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.office.plist "14\UserInfo\UserInitials" -string BM
fi